# JavaScript drawImage() not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a javascript slideshow, here is my current code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("frame");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("s1");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 190);

}


function scene2() {
  var img1 = document.getElementById("s2");
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 300, 190);
};
```

```css
.i {
  display: none;
}
canvas {
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  width: 910;
  height: 500;
}
```

```html
<img class="i" id="s1" src="Images/scene1.png"></img>
<img class="i" id="s2" src="Images/scene2.png"></img>
<canvas id="frame"></canvas>
<button onclick="scene2()">A</button>
```

But, when I press the a button to go to the next slide, it stays on the first slide. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ctx` is scoped to only the first function. It’s undefined anywhere else. Just open the browser console and look at the error messages.

Comment: @Xufox post that as an answer

Comment: May I ask why you are using Canvas, not DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function scene2 creates new scope for variables and ctx variable is not visible there. Look at this code:

```html
<html>

<img class="i" id="s1" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a"></img>
<img class="i" id="s2" src="http://hammerjs.github.io/assets/img/stackoverflow-icon.svg"></img>
<canvas id="frame"></canvas>
<button onclick="scene2()">A</button>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
var c=document.getElementById("frame");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("s1");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,300,190);

}


function scene2(){
var c=document.getElementById("frame");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img1=document.getElementById("s2");
ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0,300,190);
};
</script>

<style>
.i{
display: none;
}
canvas{
border: 5px solid #000000;
width:910;
height:500;
}
</style>

</html>
```